# Unable to run WHISPER AI Transcription on GPU or CUDA despite correct installation

Tags: python, openai-whisper

I have a Gigabyte Aorus notebook with a RTX3070 card and i'm unable to run Whisper with CUDA or GPU. I get the same error every time and i'm not sure how to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated.
Here's the error dump:

```
File "C:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Python\Scripts\whisper.exe_main.py", line 7, in
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py", line 444, in cli
model = load_model(model_name, device=device, download_root=model_dir)
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\whisper_init.py", line 144, in load_model
checkpoint = torch.load(fp, map_location=device)
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1014, in load
return _load(opened_zipfile,
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1422, in _load
result = unpickler.load()
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1392, in persistent_load
typed_storage = load_tensor(dtype, nbytes, key, _maybe_decode_ascii(location))
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1366, in load_tensor
wrap_storage=restore_location(storage, location),
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1296, in restore_location
return default_restore_location(storage, map_location)
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 381, in default_restore_location
result = fn(storage, location)
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 304, in _hpu_deserialize
assert hpu is not None, "HPU device module is not loaded"
AssertionError: HPU device module is not loaded
```

I installed the NVIDIA toolkit. CUDA returns true when i test for IsAvailable.
I even installed the cuda runtime from NVIDIA

```
pip install nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12
```

Nothing works. If i don't use the device parameter, it will default to CPU and it works fine. However, GPU keeps returning the error.

A final note is that the way i'm checking to see if it's using the GPU is that i'm checking the Taskmanager and looking at GPU usage. I also look at the AORUS control center in the dashboard to check the GPU loading as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any resolution on this? I have the same problem

Comment: same issue on colab